# Switch between different parameter values with string comparison using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How can I switch between a parameter with different choices with a string comparison?

I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {  
agent any
   stages {
        stage ('Class') {
        steps {
            script{
                switch(env.class) {
                   case { if ("${class}" == "a") }:
                        echo "match"
                    break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my jenkins job, I have a `string parameter` called `class` which is different for different jobs.
For this, If `${class}==a`, I want to do some steps. 
Someone, please let me know how I can achieve this
Thanks

Comment: `env.class` should be `params.class` and you should probably follow proper syntax by doing `case 'a':`. Does that fix your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Declarative pipeline doesn't work the same as the Scripted pipeline, but maybe you get some inspiration with this Scripted pipeline example:

```
#!groovy
node {
    properties([
            parameters([
                    choice(choices: 'a\nb',
                            description: 'Pick a letter.',
                            name: 'class')
            ])
    ])

    try {
        stage('Class') {
            switch (params.class) {
                case 'a':
                    result = "matching a"
                    // do some things if choice a is given
                    echo "Step 1"
                    break
                case 'b':
                    result = "matching b"
                    // do some things if choice b is given
                    echo "Step 2"
                    break
            }
            echo "${result}"

        }
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        // do not swallow exception
        echo "Exception: ${t}"
        throw t;
    }
}
```